# Ruby Float always show 3 digits

Tags: ruby, regex, floating-point

Currently I have this:

```
"%.3f" % [1/10]
=> 0.100
```

How can I adjust this to ALWAYS show just the first 3 digits after the decimal and drop the zero.

Example

```
"something" % [1/10]
=> .100

"something" % [2/3]
=> .667

"something" % [1/1]
=> 1.000
```

Suggestions are well appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For that particular case I would like the output to be .100 not 0.100

Comment: Do you want to drop the leading `0` before the decimal? So instead of `0.667`, you want `.667`, but `.005` should be as is?

Comment: yes correct. ideally 0.005 would be .005 and 1.005 would remain 1.005. So if zero, then drop the zero.

Comment: In your example, `10/1`, should be `1/10`, right?

Comment: yes my mistake, I just edited

Comment: You should do `Rational(1, 10)`, etc. `1/10` is `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
("%.3f" % number).sub(/\A0/, "")
```

Comment: This fits what I was looking for thank you.